# Add ASP.NET MVC and Web API Web Application in the same project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, architecture

I have created a new asp.net (standard) web api project and now I would like to have the front logic (ASP.net MVC) in the same project, I came to know that we can have both client (MVC) and server (Web API) application in the same project.
I tried to find the step by step process to follow, but I couldn't find any.
I would really appreciate if someone can provide me steps to follow, as this is the first time I'm building a application from scratch.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of .Net?  What version of web api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to create an empty asp.net project and define that this project has the web and api features. For sample:

1. in Visual Studio 2019, select the asp.net template:

[image]

2. Define the name of the project

[image]

3. Select the `Empty` and check the options, `MVC` and `Web Api`

[image]

In the `App_Start` folder you will see two files. The `RouteConfig.cs` file define the routes for the ASP.NET MVC Web App. The `WebApiConfig.cs` file define the routes for the ASP.NET Web Api application.

Importante: The API controllers has a prefix on the route called `api`, so, when you create a controller that inherits from `ApiController`, it will be routed by `api/ControllerName`.